# Modify Facebook Comments Plugin's font-size

Tags: css, iframe, facebook-social-plugins

Is there any way to modify font-size inside Facebook Comment iframe?

I tried to use jquery `append` script hoping I could inject my css file into the iframe but the result was none.
Or this is something that we can't do much about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can archive this function by using comment API to create your own style. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/comment

Answer (score 1):

The content of the iframe is separate from your parent page and there is no way to manipulate the html in the iframe unless it is a setting on Facebook side.